# Complex analysis trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to figure out how to integrate trig integrals **using complex analysis**. I have this problem... $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(t)}{4+\sin(t)}dt$$
I know that I need to make substitutions of $dz=ie^{it}dt$, $\cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$, and $\sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$. This gives for $z=e^{it}$ that $dt=\frac{dz}{iz}$, $\cos(t)=\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$, and $\sin(t)=\frac{1}{2i}(z-z^{-1})$. So the integral becomes, $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})}{4+\frac{1}{2i}(z-z^{-1})}\frac{dz}{iz}$$. I am having a really hard time after this. I don't know how to solve it from there.

Comment: But $u=4+\sin(t)$....

Comment: I know how to do these fairly well not using complex analysis but I am trying to learn a new way to do it :)

Comment: Why make simple when it's so simple to make complicated?

Comment: I agree with @Bernard, don't make it harder then you need to

Comment: Its just a concept I am trying to learn so that I can do integrals that can't be done by trig sub or other methods.

Comment: Precisely: consider integrals which *cannot* be obtained by ‘classical’ ways.

Comment: The original integral is clearly $$\left. \log(4+\sin t)\right|_{0}^{2\pi}=\color{red}{0},$$ do you really need complex tools to kill a fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})}{4+\frac{1}{2i}(z-z^{-1})}\frac{dz}{iz}$$
If the function inside the integral is denoted by $f(z)$, then $$f(z)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{8iz+(z^2-1)}=\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+8iz-1)}=\frac{z^2+1}{z(z-(4+\sqrt{15})i)(z-(4-\sqrt{15})i)}$$
The cubic on the denominator has roots as shown, so you can then see there are simple poles at $z=0,(-4\pm\sqrt{15})i$.

Then use residue theorem to evaluate the integral by using the residues at two of these points (I think one of them lies outside the unit circle).

Comment: Thank you. I am having trouble seeing what you did to get the $z^2$ in the denominator? Maybe I am missing something about the $z$ and $z^{-1}$...

Comment: To get to the point $z^2+8iz-1$, I multipled out the denominator of your integral, which is $(4+\frac1{2i}(z-z^{-1}))(iz)$, and I also multiplied by the spare $2$ from the numerator. Of course, $z\cdot z^{-1}=1.$

Comment: Oh I see it now. I forgot about the $\frac{1}{iz}$. Thanks so much.