# Calculating a real integral using complex integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{1+4\sin^2(x)}$$
Does someone know how to calculate this integral using complex integrals?

Comment: For the usual trick, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248802/complex-analysis-trigonometric-integral

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla so this question unlike the question you linked is really something that cannot be done by elementary calculus stuff right?

Comment: @BCLC, both integrals can be done by elementary calculus. In this case, the usual change is $t = \tan x$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla ah thanks. weierstrass substitution? (sort of. $x$ instead of $\frac x2$)

Comment: @BCLC, Weierstrass is another possibility. But the simpler change, *if applicable*, produces simpler integrals *usually*.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R(x)=\frac1{1+4x^2}$, the your integral is$$\int_0^{2\pi}R(\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta.$$Now, if you define$$f(z)=\frac1zR\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}\right)=-\frac z{z^4-3z^2+1},$$then\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}R(\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta&=\frac1i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{e^{i\theta}}R\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\right)ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac1i\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi\times(\text{sum of residues of $f$ in $D(0,1)$}).\end{align}So, compute the residues of $f$ at $\pm\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$.

Comment: How can I compute the sum of residues of f in D(0,1)?

Comment: Using the fact that, if $h'(a)\ne0$, then $\operatorname{res}_{z=a}\left(\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}\right)=\frac{g(a)}{h'(a)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^{iz}$, so $dx = ie^{iz} dz$, $\sin x = \frac{1}{2i} (z-z^{-1})$ and if there were a cosine term, $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$.  Simplify and find the residue of each pole inside the unit circle.